# Is it possible to modify the default SQL in query analyzer for 'edit top 200 rows'?

Tags: sql-server, query-analyzer

What if I want to edit the bottom 200 rows, or a custom query, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

1. Load the query window with the edit 200 rows
2. From the Query Designer Menu > Pane > SQL or use the SQL button from the Query Designer toolbar
3. Edit the query to the number of rows that you want or order by ID, etc
4. Execute the new query and the window will be refreshed.

Answer (score 2):

When you click on "edit Top 200 rows", there is a button on the top right corner that says "SQL", when you click on that, you can write your custom query.

[image: screenshot of SQL pane button]

If you want the default value for the *edit TOP n rows*, you can go to "Tools->Options->SQL Server  Object Explorer" and edit the 200 there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Query Analyzer, but in Management Studio you can right click and select Pane > SQL to view/edit the SQL query used